# How to dismiss the bottom search bar

Tags: the-silver-searcher

## background

So I have the silver search thing going:

```
" The Silver Searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use ag over grep
  let &grepprg = "ag --nogroup --nocolor --ignore wiki --ignore tags"

  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

  " ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif


" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
```

when I click on <kbd>\</kbd> I get the prompt to search, which is great, it looks like this:
[image]

I got three questions:

1. how do I dismiss the bottom bar? I'm not sure what that action is called.. ideally I would connect that to some keyboard binding
2. How can i make it so that when i click on a file (or perform some keybinding on a file in the list below).. it automatically jumps to the file AND dismiss the bottom bar?
3. how can I (with a keyboard shortuct) make the bottom bar *higher* and *smaller*? sometimes that's useful when i got tonnes of results

many thanks

Comment: what do you mean with the bottom bar?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt just updated the question to answer yours

Comment: That is the quickfix list. The one you opened with the `:cwindow` command. Read the help at `:h quickfix` to see what commands are available (like e.g. `:cclose` to close it)

Comment: i see.. that narrows down the search a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217825/vim-how-to-set-the-window-size-of-quickfix-window

Answer (score 1):

It's called the quickfix window. (See `:h quickfix`)

1. It can be dismissed with the command `:cclose` or with any regular window command. e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.
2. One way you could do this:

   ```
   nnoremap <expr> <CR> &buftype=='quickfix' ? "\<CR>:cclose\<CR>" : "\<CR>"
   ```

   Another alternative would be to use an autocommand to create a buffer-local mapping only in the quickfix window, or just to use a new trigger for your jump-to-error-and-close mapping. (e.g. `<leader><cr>`)
3. You can use the regular window resizing commands:

   - <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

   These take counts, so you can resize more rapidly with commands such as:

   - <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>